# Saving Image with imagejpeg

Tags: php, image, gdlib

I'm experiencing an error while saving an image with my `imagejpeg()` function.

```
$tempFile = 'temp/'.$fbme['id'].'.jpg';
imagejpeg($cardImg,$tempFile,90);
saveTrackingRecord($fbme['id'], $randomPicIdx);
```

This is the error:

> Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Please help. Thank you so much in advance.

**Update**

Here is how I initially defined `$tempfile`.

```
$tempFile = 'temp/'.$fbme['id'].'.jpg?time='.time();
```

Here is how I am giving o/p:

```
<img src="<?php echo $tempFile.'?time='.time(); ?>" style="width:90%; max-width:400px;"/></center><br/>
```

Comment: What is `$cardImg`? It should be resource, not boolean.

Comment: add the code where you define `$cardImg`

Comment: perhaps `$tempFile` does not exist

Comment: @panther it is like this `$cardImg = @imagecreatefrompng('pic/'.$randomPicIdx.'.png');`

Comment: @Shiva: okay, so now remove the `@` before function name and follow the error message.

Comment: @panther Now `Warning: imagecreatefrompng(pic/.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Shiva: I think the `warning` tells you everything. Image `pic/XXX.png` doesn't exist, or you don't have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the image with [imagetruecolor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) before passing it to the function `imagejpeg`